# g++ __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) - what is it

Tags: c++, constructor, g++, destructor

After compiling of c++ file (with global static object) I get in `nm` output this function:

```
 00000000 t _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii

 __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)  /* after c++filt */
```

What is it? It will call `__cxa_atexit()`

Can I disable generation of this function (and calling a `__cxa_atexit()`) and put all constructor and destructor calls to `.ctors` and `.dtors` sections?

Comment: g++ does have a `-fno-use-cxa-atexit` command line option but I don't think that'll help.  It looks like it just causes `atexit()` to be used instead of `cxa_atexit()`.  Perhaps the better question to ask is why g++ generates `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0()` to begin with instead of placing constructor and destructor calls in the `.ctors` and `.dtors` ELF sections.  Presumably there's a good reason for it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This doc file seems to tell ya all you'd wanna know about those functions: http://www.nsnam.org/docs/linker-problems.doc

From what I can grok, gcc creates a `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0` for every translation unit that needs static constructors to be called.  Then it places `__do_global_ctors_aux` into the `.ctors` section, which then calls `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0` on each translation unit.

The issue seems to be a lot more complex than that though; gcc has to deal with individual object files in an archive, and I think this is how they keep the linker from optimizing out those calls.